# How to find the sum of digits of $p^q$ when $p$ and $q$ are large integers?

Tags: number-theory

Is there any formula to get direct value for this function.

$F(p,q)$ = sum of digits in  $p^q$

I know that i can compute $p^q$ and sum up the digits. But I want to find it when $p$ and $q$ are big numbers. So is there any number theory formula for this?

**Edit:**  $1<=p<=9$ , $q<3000$

Comment: With your edit, it looks like a programming challenge. 9^3000 has only 2863 decimal digits, so it looks like the challenge is to implement a big number operation to make $p^q$ and add the digits.  The ranges seem chosen to make it accessible to brute force if you do the big number thing.

Comment: I don't want to do bruteforce here.

Answer (score 1):

Not that I know of, and why do you think there should be?  Sum of digits is dependent on the base.  If there are divisibility relations between $p$ and $q$, maybe.

Comment: no there is no such relation.